# Storing an ngResource call into a variable

Tags: angularjs

I'm writing an app that uses Rails to serve up a JSON api. I'm using the Angular `ngResource` module to consume those json endpoints.

While I have `ngResource`, configured correctly (see below) and can store its results into a `$scope` variable or log it out to the console, I'm having a difficult time using a service to make a `ngResource` call and have it store its results into a regular old `array` variable.

In this example, I have a resource called `Genre`, which accesses my Rails JSON api. `GenreService` injects `Genre` and attempts to make a 'Genre.index()`call and store those results into a local`Array` variable.

Here are the file contents:

#### Genre.js.coffee

```
'use strict'

app = angular.module("ATWP")

app.factory "Genre", ($resource) ->
  $resource "/genres/:slug",
    slug: "@slug"
  ,
    create:
      method: "POST"

    index:
      method: "GET"
      isArray: true

    show:
      method: "GET"

    update:
      method: "PUT"

    books:
      method: "GET"
```

#### GenreService.js.coffee

```
'use strict'

app = angular.module('ATWP')

genreService = app.factory 'GenreService', (Genre) ->

  genreResponse = new Array()

  Genre.index((response) ->
    genreResponse = response
  )

  console.log 'Genre Response'
  console.log genreResponse

  getGenres: ->
    genreResponse
```

Logging `genreResponse` at this point in time will will actually show an array. However, if I inject `GenreService` into a controller and then store the result of the `GenreService.getGenres()` into an array, that array will appear empty whenever I log it to the console.

I'm wondering why that is the case. Do I have to use the `Promise` API? Can anybody help me why understand this is happening?

Thanks guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When `console.log genreResponse`, the call hasn't completed yet, so you will have an empty array.

Try using a $watch instead (non-coffeescript):

```
$scope.$watch('genreResponse', function (newVal, oldVal) {
  if (newVal) {
    console.log($scope.genreResponse);
  }
});
```

Comment: Could I write something like $scope.$watch('genreService.getGenres()', function (newVal, OldVal) { .... and still have it work?

Comment: Haven't had time to try it, but most likely

Comment: Using $watch inside a directive solved my problems. I have edited the above answer to show what got working for me.